# altering a table column

Tags: sql-server-2005, alter-table

```
create  table Names (
   FirstName  varchar(40),
   LastName  varchar(40),
   FullName  AS FirstName+LastName
)
```

but now, in the full name i want that a space is inserted between first and last name, so i am altering the table but it gives syntax error. how to alter it.

```
alter table Names
alter column fullname as FirstName+' '+LastName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
alter table Names drop column fullname 
alter table Names add fullname as FirstName+' '+LastName
```

Comment: +1 Looking at `ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN` in BOL I think this is the only way. `<computed_column_definition>` only appears under `ADD`

Answer (score 2):

You can not ALTER computed columns. You can drop and recreate